# use variable in fieldname in a cfloop

Tags: coldfusion, cfml, railo, lucee

I have several fields in a database called p1, p2, p3 and so on, they are being returned by a query called GetUser. I want to check their values, but the following code errors out on me. I'm sure my formatting 'GetUser.p#x#' is wrong, but I cannot figure out how to do it. Any help would be much appreciated.

I have the following code, which works...

```
    <cfquery name="GetUser"> 
        SELECT id, p00, p01, p02, p03, p04, p05, p06
        FROM users 
        where id = #session.user_id#
    </cfquery>

    <cfoutput query="GetUser">
        <cfif p01 is 1><li>Post 01</li></cfif>
        <cfif p02 is 1><li>Post 02</li></cfif>
        <cfif p03 is 1><li>Post 03</li></cfif>
        <cfif p04 is 1><li>Post 04</li></cfif>
        <cfif p05 is 1><li>Post 05</li></cfif>
        <cfif p06 is 1><li>Post 06</li></cfif>
    </cfoutput>
```

Naturally, this is an awful way of doing this, so I wanted to do a loop like as follows to achieve the same result:

```
    <cfloop index = "x" from = "1" to = "6"> 
        <cfif GetUser.p0#x# is 1><li>Post #x#</li></cfif>
    </cfloop>
```

Bt this errors out.   So I am looking to understand how to achieve this.

// There is a similar question that suggest queryName["columnName"][rowNumber] is required.  This is different, and simpler.

Comment: `getUser['p0' +x]`is the syntax for a dynamic variable within your query.

Comment: That should say "from your query"

Comment: Close, but not quite.       <cfloop index = "x" from = "0" to = "9"> 
        <cfif getUser['p0' + x] is 1><li>Post 0#x#</li></cfif>
    </cfloop> results in error: can't cast [p0] string to a number value.

Comment: sorrysorry, too much java lately. Should have been & instead of +

Answer (score 1):

OK, got it...   the answer was:

```
 <cfloop index = "x" from = "1" to = "10">
   <cfif getUser['p0' & x] is 1><li> 0#x#</li> </cfif>
 </cfloop>
```

Matt Busche almost had it.  getUser['p0' +x] needed o be getUser['p0' & x]

Thanks!

Comment: Is that the complete working code? Typically dynamic query column references also require a row number, ie `queryName["columnName"][rowNumber]`.  See example: http://trycf.com/gist/b304d69d93f16b4822a3455118fbc266/acf2016?theme=monokai

Comment: Yes, it is complete working code, and is different from the one marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Both threads ask how to access query columns dynamically. The answer is the same: use associative array notation.  Granted, Lucee/Railo may allow you to omit the query row number. ACF does not.  The snippet above does not compile. It is missing the missing a closing CFIF tag.

Comment: That may be correct.  I am using Lucee 5.  But for what it is worth, the other thread was unclear to me.  I looked through it before posting this question.  BTW:  Fixed the </CFIF>

Comment: Thanks for updating the answer. BTW, if the column values are always 1 or 0, you could also use the shortcut `<cfif getUser['p0' & x]>`. CF will implicitly convert numeric values to a boolean. The value 0 equates to `false`. Any other number (1, -1, etectera) evaluates to `true`. Also, do not forget to use `cfqueryparam` on all variable query parameters. It boosts performance and helps protect queries against sql injection.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Edited for clarity:

```
<cfquery name="getuser"  datasource="STACK">
    Select * from stackoverflow
</cfquery>

<cfset fieldNumber = #ListLen(getuser.ColumnList)#>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to="#fieldNumber#"> 
This is P#i#
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

It seems from your comment you want conditional checks based on the column you are returning. Assuming your columns are named consistently, the column returned should always match the iteration of the loop. You should only have to loop over as many fields as you have, and this way it will always do exactly that without having to hard-code a 10 or whatever.

So instead of checking if the value is p1 or p2, you can just use `#i#`, e.g.:

`<cfif i is 1> P1 is here. </cfif>`

Comment: I think I need to be more clear.  I have the following field names in my table:  p0, p1, p2, p3, etc.   I am doing this loop to check the values in these fields in a query.   so p#x#  should check getuser.p1, then getuser.p2, and so on.  p is not a variable.  It is a constant in the field names.

Comment: Updated answer. I got some mental wires crossed and assumed you were looping over form fields for some reason.

Comment: Hi, I think it is still unclear what I am trying to do.  I updated the question to be extremely specific as to what I am trying to achieve.  Sorry for my lack of clarity.