# How do I accomplish nesting a loop iteration in a variable inside a loop in CFML

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml, coldfusion-11, lucee

I am trying to loops through a json response in CFML, and need to do one call to get the number of pages, then a call for each successive page, then loop through items to get my data.  In doing so I have a nested loop that requires a nested variable.  So, for example, my initial loop will result in:

```
#jsonarray.items.1.id#
#jsonarray.items.2.id#
#jsonarray.items.3.id#
#jsonarray.items.4.id#
and so on.
```

So in my inside loop, I am trying to replace that number by doing another loop like this:

```
  <cfloop from="1" to="50" index="thisBatchItem">
  </cfloop>
```

But then, I would have to nest the index inside my variable, and that of course does not work.

Can someone point to what I am missing here?

Here is the code I am working with, and you will see the obvious places where I have the problem.  I put in **#jsonarray.items.#thisBatchItem#.id#** just to show where I am trying to make this happen.  I know it does not work.

```
<cfhttp method="GET" result="httpResp" url="https://example.com/api?filter[batch.date][gte]=2022-02-01&filter[batch.date][lte]=2022-03-07&page=1&per-page=50" throwonerror="false">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-type" value="application/json">
</cfhttp>            

<cfoutput>
    <cfloop from="1" to="#pageCount#" index="thisPage">

        <cfhttp method="GET" result="httpResp" url="https://example.com/api?filter[batch.date][gte]=2022-02-01&filter[batch.date][lte]=2022-03-07&page=#thisPage#&per-page=50" throwonerror="false">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Authorization" value="Bearer XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
            <cfhttpparam type="header" name="Content-type" value="application/json">
        </cfhttp>            
        <cfset jsonarray = deserializeJson(httpResp.fileContent)>
        <cfloop from="1" to="50" index="thisBatchItem">
            <cfif StructKeyExists(jsonarray,"#jsonarray.items.#thisBatchItem#.id#")>
                #jsonarray.items.[#thisBatchItem#].id#<br>
            </cfif>
        </cfloop>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Are you looking for bracket notation?

Comment: It seems as though you've used the technique you're looking for in your previous Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38548910/use-variable-in-fieldname-in-a-cfloop/38554601#38554601

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `items` is an array of structures, it's simpler and cleaner to use an "array" loop.

If some of the structure keys are optional, try using the [safe navigation operator](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/using/language-enhancements.html) `?.`. In the example below, it prevents an error from occurring when the code uses a non-existent key name like "lookMaNoErrors"?

```
<cfset jsonResponse = deserializeJson(httpResp.fileContent)>
<cfloop array="#jsonResponse.items#" index="currentItem">
    id #currentItem.id#<br> 
    lookMaNoErrors #currentItem?.lookMaNoErrors#<br>
</cfloop>
```

**Update:**

To answer the original question, you need to use structure notation. Also, instead of hard coding the upper limit of the loop, use the array length instead:

```
<cfloop from="1" to="#arrayLen(jsonResponse.items)#" index="itemIndex">
    id #jsonResponse.items[itemIndex].id#            
    
</cfloop>
```

[demo trycf.com](https://trycf.com/gist/99c8be41e9aa872feeef0d7aaf5ca988/acf2021?theme=monokai)

Comment: Perfect!  Works like a charm.   Still not sure how to nest tags as mentioned above with bracket notation, but this entirely solved my issue!  Thanks

Comment: See my updated answer and the trycf.com example

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for that.  Obviously the array loop made more sense, but a direct answer also helps for other similar situations that may not involve an array.  Huge help!